# Structural pattern matching and infinity

Tags: python, structural-pattern-matching

I am computing the *Lp* distance functions for non-negative *p*'s. For all but *p* = 0 and *p* = ∞ a built-in `pow()` function serves well.
Before I learned about a structural pattern matching, I had used a dictionary and exception handling:

```
from math import sqrt, inf
distance_function = {   0.0: lambda x, y: int(x != 0.0) + int(y != 0.0),
                        1.0: lambda x, y: abs(x) + abs(y), # Likely a tad faster than 'pow()'       
                        inf: lambda x, y: max(abs(x), abs(y))}                  
def lp_distance(x, y, p): 
    try:                return distance_function[p](x, y)                   
    except KeyError:    return pow(pow(abs(x), p) + pow(abs(y), p), 1.0/p)
```

Some people didn't want exceptions here. So I rewrote the snippet into the following one:

```
def lp_distance(x, y, p):
    match p:
        case 0.0:           return int(x != 0.0) + int(y != 0.0)
        case 1.0:           return abs(x) + abs(y)      
        # The line below triggers "SyntaxError: name capture 'inf' makes remaining patterns unreachable"
        case inf:           return max(abs(x), abs(y))
        # But the following works:
        case p if p == inf: return max(abs(x), abs(y))
        case _:             return pow(pow(abs(x), p) + pow(abs(y), p), 1.0/p)
```

Why `case inf:` is not correct (**Python v3.10.2**)?

Comment: My guess from working on scientific computing before is that `inf`, `-inf` and `NaN` actually follow IEEE rules (I think 754 specifically). And according to those rules, `inf` is only closer to themselves. In this case, I think all patterns are `OR`ed and probably that is causing just using `inf` to result into `inf` always and hence unreachable for other patterns. If you do `1 and p == inf` instead of `p if p == inf`, I think it should work as well. I don't have `3.10` atm, will try this myself tonight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a `case` statement, [a *simple* name is a pattern that *captures* (assigns) to that name](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#capture-patterns). In contrast, [a *dotted* name is a patterns that refers to the *value* of that name](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#value-patterns).

> In simple terms `NAME` will always succeed and it will set `NAME = <subject>`.

> In simple terms `NAME1.NAME2` will succeed only if `<subject> == NAME1.NAME2`

Using just `case inf:` means that the value to match is unconditionally assigned to the name `inf` – it does not matter if the name was previously bound.
What you want instead is `case math.inf:`, which means to compare against this value.

```py
import math

def lp_distance(x, y, p):
    match p:
        case 0.0:
            return int(x != 0.0) + int(y != 0.0)
        case 1.0:
            return abs(x) + abs(y)      
        # compare against a value by using its dotted name
        case math.inf:
            return max(abs(x), abs(y))
        case _:
            return pow(pow(abs(x), p) + pow(abs(y), p), 1.0/p)
```

Answer (score 2):

As noted by the other respondents, you can't use *inf* directly because that is a capture pattern.   The obvious solution is to use a *value* pattern with a dotted lookup; however, **that only works for positive infinity**.

To handle other all special values like negative infinity and NaNs, you need guards:

```
match x:
    case 1.0: ...                   # Exact value (literal pattern)
    case 0.0: ...                   # Exact value (literal pattern)
    case _ if math.isfinite(x): ... # Normal cases
    case _ if math.isnan(x): ...    # NaNs defy equality tests
    case _: ...                     # Negative infinity
```